# Storing and Calling Expressions with IronPython in Spotfire

Tags: scripting, ironpython, calculated-columns, spotfire

Is there anyway to store an expression in an IronPython script in Spotfire, and then call on it later to simplify my scripts where I am adding a bunch of calculated columns? 
Some of my expressions are simply (A+B), but i am also trying to see if it is possible to store an if then "case statement" as an expression

For example:

expression1 = [VarA] * 3.289

expression2 ~ (VarA] / [VarB]) * 23.33

expression3 = Case
              When [VarA] = 1 Then "Blue"
              Else "Red"
              End

---

example script (this works):

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import CalculatedColumn
cols = Document.Data.Tables["MyTable"].Columns
cols.AddCalculatedColumn("NewColumn1","[VarA] * 3.289");
```

Example of what I'd like to do:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import CalculatedColumn
cols = Document.Data.Tables["MyTable"].Columns
cols.AddCalculatedColumn("NewColumn1","expression1");
cols.AddCalculatedColumn("NewColumn2","expression2");
cols.AddCalculatedColumn("NewColumn3","expression3");
```

Answer (score 1):

I mean maybe I'm not understanding you but I think just make expression1 a variable like you were trying to do. Make sure you use quotation marks for strings and don't use them for variables.

```
expression1 = "[varA]*3.289"
cols.AddCalculatedColumn("NewColumn1",expression1)
```